# Get number of days balance was negative

Tags: sql-server

I would like to get the number of days the account went to a negative balance.

I have the following Balance table.

```
|AccNo |    Amount      | Date
------------------------------------
|1     |    -8775.76    | 2019-05-31 
|1     |    -697.05     | 2019-05-30
|1     |    -3504.52    | 2019-05-29
|1     |   +1783.67     | 2019-05-28
|1     |    -14204.55   | 2019-05-27


  SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, AccountB.Date, GETDATE()) AS DaysInDebit
  FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Date
        FROM Balance WHERE AccNo = 1
        AND Amount > 0
        ORDER BY Date DESC
       ) AS AccountB
  ORDER BY AccountB.Date DESC
```

I am expecting to get 3 days where the account was in debt.
Result set from 2019-05-28 to 2019-05-31. Date Difference = 3

Comment: Please add your expected result set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT 
DATEDIFF
(
    DD,
    (
        SELECT 
        MAX(Date) 
        FROM your_table 
        WHERE ID= 1
        AND Amount > 0
    ),
    GETDATE()
)
FROM your_table 
WHERE ID = 1
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by finding `max()` for the last positive balance.

```
select
    count(*) as NumberOfDays
from Balance
where [Date] > (select max([Date]) from Balance where Amount > 0 and AccNo = 1)
and AccNo = 1
```